# How to whitelist Firebase Web App with Mongo Atlas?

Tags: firebase, mongodb-atlas, whitelist, cidr

What is the correct way to white list my Firebase Web App with Mongo Atlas? **Specifically, MongoDB Atlas queries coming from my Firebase Cloud Functions.**

The functions work fine using the Firebase Emulators and whitelisting my dev/home IP. They also work fine if I ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE. How do I secure this connection just to the deployed Firebase Web App?

[image: Mongo Atlas White List]

The web app lives on `<app-name>.cloudfunctions.net`. When I run nslookup, it returns

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <app-name>.cloudfunctions.net
Address: 151.101.65.195
Name:   <app-name>.cloudfunctions.net
Address: 151.101.1.195
```

If I follow the instructions to generate CIDR-notated range, I get all these networks. I've tried adding them all but get cloud function errors (rejection error and then crash). I've tried variations on these ranges through trial and error but it's not enabling a connection.

What is the correct notation (or method) to whitelist a Firebase web app?

[image]

Comment: Are you making calls to your MongoDB directly from frontend?

Comment: No, calls are coming from FB Cloud Functions. I edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you should look at whitelisting Cloud Functions IP address but they may not be static. However you can try methods as listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip). I'm not completely sure if they'll work for Firebase Cloud Function...

Comment: oh boy.... that looks very, VERY, complicated :-(

Comment: Well security stuff... I'll try it myself and get back to you asap.